# Бесконечное чтение из clipboard

Tags: java, android

Можно ли сделать бесконечное чтение скопированного текста из clipboard'a?

К примеру, если скопировать текст - он моментально появился в toast'e.

P.S Пробовал писать такой код - не работает

```
public class service extends Service {
    public ClipboardManager clipboardManager;
    public ClipData data;
    public String get;
    public  Runnable runnable;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread my = new Thread(runnable);
        my.start();
        clipboardManager=(ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    myy();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public void myy(){

        data = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
        if (data !=null) {
            ClipData.Item items = data.getItemAt(0);
            get = items.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), get, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Бесконечный цикл и без пауз - это совсем не хорошо. Попробуйте решение с en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287217

Comment: Спасибо огромное, всё работает)